# XGB predict always return same value when predict outside train value

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost, predict

im building some machine learning using XGB to predict the qty based on price of the product
here's my data

```
df <- structure(list(price= c(80000, 85000, 87000, 88000, 89000, 
90000, 91000, 92000, 93000, 94000, 95000, 96000, 97000, 98000, 
102000, 106000, 107000, 108000, 110000, 111000, 112000, 113000, 
114000, 115000, 116000, 117000, 118000, 119000), qty = c(1, 212, 
298, 243, 309, 195, 248.75, 377, 179, 111, 311.75, 115, 274.5, 
121.571428571429, 143, 128.5, 203, 215, 193, 198, 128, 136.25, 
134.666666666667, 124.125, 125.75, 144.3, 148.142857142857, 115.333333333333
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -28L))
```

and here's my code for my model

```
trcontrol <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                          number = 10,
                          repeats = 3)

tune_grid <- expand.grid(nrounds = 200,
            max_depth = 5,
            eta = 0.05,
            gamma = 0.01,
            colsample_bytree = 0.75,
            min_child_weight = 0,
            subsample = 0.5
            )

model_train_xgb <- train(qty~price, data = df, 
                         method = "xgbTree", 
                         trControl = trcontrol,
                         tuneGrid = tune_grid,
                         verbose = FALSE,
                         objective = "reg:squarederror")
```

im wondering why when i predict using this model outside the value of the train data it always return the same.

for example if i predict using this code

```
predict(model_train_xgb, tibble(price= 150000))
```

it will returned `119.7586`, and if i change into higher number it always return `119.7586`.
it will returned the same number if i change into whatever number as long the number are higher than the train data.
can you tell me why?

thanks

Comment: 1. You'll probably need more signals to do the prediction. You have only one input feature so far. 2. You haven't done any parameter tuning. You need to select the right number of parameters for the model.

Comment: That's just how tree models work.  As such, this question isn't about programming or the xgboost package, but about how tree (ensemble) models work, and so belongs on stats.SE or datascience.SE.